# Creating a reference number then resetting the count when condition is met

Tags: django

I have created a piece of code that generates a reference number for my system. I can generate it the way I want it. But I don't have idea how to reset it's counting when year is added by 1.

I override the save function in django so every time I hit save, it will generate the reference for me.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    yr = datetime.now()
    yrnum = yr.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    if self.system == 'Software':
        self.refNo = 'S%s-%03d' % (yrnum, int(self.ticketCount)) #ticketCount is a CharField that stores the count of the rows, the thing I want to reset when yrnum is added by 1.
    else:
        self.refNo = 'A%s-%03d' % (yrnum, int(self.ticketCount))
    super(tblTicket, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

It's output is:

```
A20151021-001
A20151021-002
A20151021-003
```

Then when the year changes to **2016**, I want the sequence to reset to 1. Like this:

```
A20151021-115
A20151121-116
A20151221-117
...
A20160101-001
A20160101-002
A20160101-003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is, you can give your model an IntegerField (called currentYear) which saves the current year as an integer when initializing the object. Then, in your save function, you can do a check like this:

```
year = datetime.date.today().year
if year > self.currentYear: # This means it is one year ahead of currentYear (this will occur on Jan 1st of every year)
    self.currentYear += 1 # currentYear is now the current year again.
    self.ticketCount = 1 # reset the ticket count for the new year
```

Comment: Okay. I will try this. I found a code but it does not increment the count.. So I will give this a shot and get back to you